# Latin to Base Char conversation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am having a file which contain Latin characters. I am using the below statement to convert into base characters below statement facilitates be the conversion but not up to the mark. for ex. I have name as PRASHNTÉ it convert into Prashnte. But I need it string same as it is file. I know here I have used inticap the reason being initials are getting converted into caps. But I need output like PRASHNTE. and if file has name as Landi Châtel I need it to be like Landi Chatel.Over all whatever case in the file I need the same should insert into the table.

```
select inticap(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('PRASHNTÉ', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))) str2
from dual
```

Comment: Try `CONVERT('PRASHNTÉ', 'US7ASCII') `

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Thanks just wanted to know it will not impact the length after the conversion? why I am asking because it is handoff file which will be used in production.

Comment: I tried this query :- SELECT CONVERT('PRAsHNTÉABñÉäßÑéàâ', 'US7ASCII')from dual; and it give output as PRAsHNTEAB?Ea??eaa

Comment: Yes, because they have no ASCII representation. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91): *Unlike many other letters that use diacritic marks (such as Ü in Spanish and German and Ç in French and Portuguese), Ñ in Spanish, Galician, Asturian, Leonese, and Filipino is considered a letter in its own right, has its own name (in Spanish: eñe), and its own place in the alphabet (after N).*

Comment: What is the purpose of this conversion?

Comment: @Wernfried https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Purpose is any of the accent characters which appear in file should be converted to base characters and get inserted into the table.

Comment: Yes but why? What is the intention? Character `é` is different to `e`! Perhaps, do you try to find a workaround for a simple display problem? We are in 2017 where "ASCII-only" character sets should not exist anymore.

Comment: As it is handoff file and client expectation is name should appear as it is in processing file removing Latin Characters as base characters.

Comment: Then you should ask your client for a translation table. Once you have such table you can use the [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions232.htm#SQLRF06145) function